# Confusion Between Associated and Principle-G-Bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, gauge

I realize there have been similar questions on stack before, but none of them have answered what I'm after.

-My question is really whether I can import wholesale everything from the principle bundle into the associated bundle $ad(P)$. Can I say that a curvature form on the principal $G$ bundle converts to a curvature form on the associated bundle, and a connection likewise? (is there a one-one correspondence between connections and curvature on the principal bundle and the associated bundle?)

-The book by Baez seems to follow this approach ("https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/2324") but I can't marry this with what is done in terms of saying a local form for the gauge potential is a pullback by a section of the connection on the principle bundle (as in say, Nakahara).

-Even if I look at just the basic case of $U(1)$, how can I convert gauge transformations (which are normally kinds of automorphisms of the principal bundle) into the associated bundle?

-Some references seem to suggest that gauge transformations on assosciated bundles are active transformations, as opposed to passive ones, but this I really don't get...

Comment: A curvature form induces a curvature endomorphism in the associated
Bundle, and a connection form induces a connection in the assosiated bundle.
(Using the covariant derivative in the principal bundle.) Meanwhile,
a connection induces a connection form, so the two notions are equivalent.
A reference might be ,,Spin Geometry'' by  H. Blaine, Jr.; Michelsohn, Marie-Louise Lawson .
Gauge transformations are in one to one correspondence with
functions from the Bundle to the structure group, acting via fibrewise multiplication, which can be carried over to the associated bundle.

Comment: I half follow you, but I'm not sure how. Given $\omega \in \Omega^{1}(P,\mathfrak{g})$, $\mathcal{F}= d\omega +[\omega,\omega] \in \Omega^{2}(P,\mathfrak{g})$, how do I get $\nabla \in \Omega^{1}(\mathcal{M},E)$, $F_{\nabla} \in \Omega^{2}(\mathcal{M},End(E))$ uniquely? Where $E:=P\times_{ad} \mathfrak{g}$

Comment: First, $\nabla$ is not a 1 form, its a map $\nabla: \Omega^0(M,E) \to
 \Omega^1(M,E)$. Sencondy, given the covariant derivative $D_A$
induced by  the connection form $A$, you may set
$\nabla_X \Psi(x) = [p, (D_A)_p (\psi(X^*))_p] $ where $p$ is in the fibre
over x,  $X^*$ is the horizontal Lift of $X$, and $\psi$ the horizontal form in the principal bundle corresponding to the section $\Psi$.

Comment: Ah should be $End(E)$? - If: $\nabla  \; : \mathscr{X}(\mathcal{M}) \times \Gamma(E) \rightarrow \Gamma(E)$ ,  $\nabla \in \Omega^{1}(\mathcal{M},End(E)) $

Comment: Yup, sounds right!
In case my previous comment is a bit confusing: there went sth wrong while
typing, it should read $\nabla_X \Psi(x) = [p,(D_A \psi)_p X^*_p]$

Comment: The thing is... if we define the exterior covariant derivative $D_{A}$, where $A$ is the local form of a (Koszul connection) then we need a connection on $P\times_{ad} \mathfrak{g}$ already?

Comment: Yes,  but you can start with a connection form on the principal bundle without a given connection on $P \times_{ad} \mathfrak{g}$